# How to solve PHP with such error: Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, contact-form

I keep getting this error messages below when I click Send button on my contact form on the website. It can't load properly mail.php. Is there anybody has any idea how I should fix this problem. Thanks.

**Warning:** Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

**Fatal error:** Unknown: Failed opening required '/home/content/08/10304008/html/gd.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_3/lib/php') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: use `header('location:include_url');exit();` while page redirect .see the browser url.Then add `../` before as respected path to reach

Comment: it still doesn't work...

Comment: I m not give solution.i just give a idea to find tha path problem.many no if time.i using this method to solve path problem.check  `basename` https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067549/include-paths-in-included-file-fail&ved=2ahUKEwjB4LD924ThAhUM73MBHRZJB-EQjjgwAHoECAcQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2Csf-3xyV1DyTlrB9hjjPc